# How can I end 18.04.1 download correctly?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, samba, downloads

I downloaded the 18.04.1 .iso of 1.8 GB four times and every time it failed right at the end with the same error:

```
Aug 14 21:34:08 Charles-PC gnome-session[2018]: Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Permission denied
Aug 14 21:34:08 Charles-PC gnome-session[2018]: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Aug 14 21:34:08 Charles-PC gnome-session[2018]: Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
Aug 14 21:34:11 Charles-PC org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1884]: ** (gvfsd:1950): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused
Aug 14 21:34:11 Charles-PC org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1884]: ** (process:14086): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Aug 14 21:34:14 Charles-PC org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1884]: ** (gvfsd:1950): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused
Aug 14 21:34:14 Charles-PC org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1884]: ** (process:14089): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Aug 14 21:35:47 Charles-PC org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1884]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2587): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to download with wget.

Run this commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install wget

wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Comment: Greetings abu_bua. In which directory would I find the .iso after wget? Thanks for advice.

Comment: in the same dir where you invoked the wget command.